# S3 based dropbox like program for mac os and windows

Tags: windows, mac, dropbox, amazon-s3

I use dropbox to sync file between several computers. It does the job quite well but it have several disadvantages:

- Storing files on S3 is much cheaper (I need about 10Gb for all my shared files) and for the same money I am able to have much more space
- It doesn't provide user side security, i.e. dropbox knows what I am storing

Are there any alternatives which provide similar functionality but without a third party like dropbox? I have taken a look at FUSE for Mac OS X but it doesn't have a windows version and I can't use my files when I am offline.

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but there are 2 programs that are close to what you ar looking for: Arq does what you need, but it is Mac OSX only: http://www.haystacksoftware.com/arq/. Cyberduck works on Mac and Windows and can use S3, but you need to upload/download files manually: http://cyberduck.ch/

Comment: Check also this for more answers: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/665/is-there-a-tool-to-sync-files-from-a-pc-to-amazon-s3-or-azure-storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on the http://www.jungledisk.com
Win and Mac OS versions, and you can use Amazon S3 in US or EU!! or RackSpace as your storage.

Comment: I have to say: The company seems quite inactive now.I love JD and it already helped me several times to get a file back. I'm currently looking for a replacement. The software *does work* though.